# Is the zig-zag lemma natural if the diagram of short exact sequences is only commutative up to homotopy?

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

Consider two exact sequences of chain complexes (of abelian groups)
with morphisms of chain complexes $f, g, h$ between them:$\require{AMScd}$
$$
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A_\bullet @>\alpha>> B_\bullet @>\beta>> C_\bullet @>>> 0\\
& @VfVV @VgVV @VhVV \\
0 @>>> X_\bullet @>\xi>> Y_\bullet @>\nu>> Z_\bullet @>>> 0
\label{d1} \tag{1}
\end{CD}
$$
If both squares in the diagram are commutative, the naturality of the zig-zag lemma gives us a morphism between the two long exact sequences, i. e. the diagram
$$
\begin{CD}
@>>> H_n(A_\bullet) @>>> H_n(B_\bullet) @>>> H_n(C_\bullet) @>\delta>> H_{n-1}(A_\bullet) @>>> \\
&@Vf_*VV @Vg_*VV @Vh_*VV @Vf_*VV \\
@>>> H_n(X_\bullet) @>>> H_n(Y_\bullet) @>>> H_n(Z_\bullet) @>\delta>> H_{n-1}(X_\bullet) @>>>
\end{CD}
$$
is commutative. Actually, the only nontrivial part of this is the commutativity of the the right square with the connecting morphisms $\delta$.

**Question:** What happens if the squares in diagram (\ref{d1}) are only commutative up to homotopy? My intuition told me that the zig-zag lemma should still be true, but I can't manage to prove it and I am actually starting to doubt whether this could really work. Again, the only nontrivial part is the commutativity of the squares with the $\delta$s.

**Edit:** I guess that this is equivalent to asking whether the zig-zag lemma is still valid in the homotopy category of chain complexes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1547503/90543) gives the following counterexample. $\newcommand\toby\xrightarrow$

Let $k$ be a field.
Take $B= \cdots\to 0 \to k \toby{1} k \to 0 \to \cdots$, with $k$s in degrees $0$ and $1$. (Arrows going to the right for notational convenience, but still with homological grading.)
Let $A$ be the subcomplex $\cdots \to 0 \to 0 \to k \to 0 \to \cdots$, with a $k$ in degree $0$. Then $C=B/A$ has a $k$ in degree $1$.
Then the diagram
$$
\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
0 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> B/A @>>> 0 \\
@. @VV1V @VV1V @VV0V @. \\
0 @>>> A @>>> B @>>> B/A @>>> 0 \\
\end{CD}
$$
commutes up to homotopy. The first square clearly commutes, and $B$ is contractible,
the nullhomotopy being $\cdots \leftarrow 0 \leftarrow k \overset{1}{\leftarrow} k \leftarrow 0 \leftarrow \cdots$, so any two maps out of $B$ are homotopic.

Then the LES in homology is the following
$$
\begin{CD}
 0=H_1(B) @>>> H_1(B/A) @>\delta>> H_0(A) @>>> H_0(B)= 0\\
@. @VV0V @VV1V @. \\
 0=H_1(B) @>>> H_1(B/A) @>\delta>> H_0(A) @>>> H_0(B) = 0,\\
\end{CD}
$$
which becomes
$$
\begin{CD}
 0 @>>> k @>1>> k @>>> 0\\
@. @VV0V @VV1V @. \\
 0 @>>> k @>1>> k @>>> 0,\\
\end{CD}
$$
which does not commute.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding something, the zero map should be from $H_1(B/A)\to H_1(B/A)$ and the map $H_0(A)\to H_0(A)$ should be the identity.

Comment: @JackozeeHakkiuz yeah, that looks right. I probably copied and pasted the top diagram and edited it into the bottom one or something. Thanks for catching it.